# Error building a R package with CUDA file

Tags: c++, r, makefile, rcpp, r-package

I'm trying to create a R package with inside a CUDA script.
The steps I've followed are simple:

- creation the package skeleton using R package RcppEigen;
- run the function compileAttributes() inside the package;
- copy the three file (.cu, .cpp, .cuh) inside src folder of the package;
- build the package with the command  R CMD build packagename;
- intall the package with the command R CMD INSTALL packagename;

But, when I try to build the package I obtain this error:

[image]

The package is called Pack and these are the three file that I have copied inside src folder

Test.cpp

```
#include "Test.cuh"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <RcppEigen.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void Test(){
     int i = 3;
     norm(i);
}
```

Test.cuh

```
#pragma once
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <RcppEigen.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]


// [[Rcpp::export]]
void norm(int i);
```

Test.cu

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Test.cuh>
#include <RcppEigen.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

 __global__ void test_kernel(void) {

 }

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void norm(int i){   
    test_kernel <<<1, 1>>> ();
    printf("%d",i);
```

Probably I'm forgetting some steps. I have also produced a Makevars file that compile all the files but the error remains the same.

Makevars:

```
CUDA_HOME = /usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit
R_HOME = /usr/lib/R

R_INC = /usr/share/R/include

CUDA_INC = /home/simo/Documents/UNI/Architettura_avanzata/Progetto/Cpp/Normalization/Pack/include
NVCC = $(CUDA_HOME)/bin/nvcc

NVCC_FLAGS = -Xcompiler "-fPIC" -w -std=c++11 -I$(R_INC)

LIBS = -lcudart -d

### Define objects
cu_sources := $(wildcard *cu)
cu_sharedlibs := $(patsubst %.cu, %.o,$(cu_sources))

cpp_sources := $(wildcard *.cpp)
cpp_sharedlibs := $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(cpp_sources))

OBJECTS = $(cu_sharedlibs) $(cpp_sharedlibs)

all : rcppcuda.so

rcppcuda.so: $(OBJECTS)

%.o: %.cpp $(cpp_sources)
    g++ $< -c -fPIC -I$(R_INC) -I$(CUDA_INC) $(LIBS)

%.o: %.cu $(cu_sources)
    $(NVCC) $(NVCC_FLAGS) -I$(CUDA_INC) $< -c
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: For starters, you have to compile CUDA with nvcc, not R's default compiler. So at the very least you need a configuration file to point you towards nvcc and a fallback if it doesnt exist.

Comment: @thc Thank's, you have any guide that I can follow or a configuration file already done?